# teradata query to analyse a particular DOB and convert it to max date of that particular month

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I want to build a teradata query that will analyse the DOB field of a table and use case statement to update accordingly. It will keep the month and year fields as it is and change the date as per below rule :

1. If the date is between 1-15 , it will be converted to last date of that particular month .
2. If the date is between 16-31 , it will be converted to first date of that particular month .

For an example, 02/13/2000 will be transformed to 02/29/2000 and 03/31/1993 will become 03/01/1993 .

I have tried below query:

```
update Table_1 
From Table_2
    set DOB =
        CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM DOB)BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN
                LAST_DAY(DOB)
            WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM DOB)BETWEEN 16 AND 31 THEN
                DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DOB)||'-'||EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DOB)||'-01')
            ELSE DOB
        END
WHERE Table_1.ID= Table_2.ID;
```

but keep getting error like "update failed. expected something like an 'end' keyword between the 'date' keyword and '(' " , however I can't  find the syntactical error.

can anyone please help to modify the query ?

Comment: To get the first day of the month, use this syntax: `ADD_MONTHS(dob- EXTRACT(DAY FROM dob)+1, 0)`

Comment: BTW, I might suggest storing this derived value in a new column, instead of changing the  DOB column.  Once you change it, you can't get it back.

Comment: There's no `DATE` function in Teradata (and it's a strange logic): `CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM DOB) <=15 THEN
                LAST_DAY(DOB)
            ELSE Trunc(DAY, 'month')        END;`  No need for the 2nd WHEN because there's no day outside of 1-31.

Comment: I don't know why I always forget the trunc function.  BTW, I think @dnoeth meant `trunc (dob, 'month')`.

Comment: @Andrew Of course, should be `trunc (dob, 'month')` *Cut & paste & forget to modify*

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response. I have modified the query and it is working as expected now. The corrected query looks like below :

update e
from Table_1 e,
 Table_2 o
 SET DOB = CASE
  WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM e.DOB) BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN
   LAST_DAY(e.DOB)
  WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM e.DOB) BETWEEN 16 AND 31 THEN 
   e.DOB - (EXTRACT(DAY FROM e.DOB) -1) 
  ELSE e.DOB END